# How can i edit my characters mesh without it teleporting off to another location?

Tags: edit-mode, pose-mode

I tried to set the armature to rest position. But that only does so much. Can i edit the character where it is in space? Or do i have to follow it where it goes in edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the *Edit* and the *On Cage* options of the Armature modifier and you'll see the mesh as it is transformed by the armature. That said, unfortunately, the gizmos stay where the vertices originally are.

[image]